# capistrano output - what are [ -L ...] commands?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a rails 4 app deployed with capistrano. In my output there are a bunch of commands running that I do not understand at all. I'm trying to figure out why some of them fail, but the real problem is I don't know what they are doing at all.

Here is a typical example:

```
DEBUG [8020adb4] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L ~/apps/spo/releases/20160205133156/public/assets ] as spo@dev.platform.spisales.com
DEBUG [8020adb4] Command: [ -L ~/apps/spo/releases/20160205133156/public/assets ]
DEBUG [8020adb4] Finished in 0.013 seconds with exit status 1 (failed).
```

I know that /usr/bin/env will run a program, but I have no idea what this part is trying to do:
`[ -L ~apps/spo/releases/20160205133156/public/assets ]`

Something like this: `/usr/bin/env mkdir` is easy to understand, it is running mkdir.

If anyone can explain what these `[ -L ...]` commands are doing I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets are an alternative syntax for the `test` command.

Which test is run depends on the expression you give, in this case it checks whether `~/apps/spo/releases/20160205133156/public/assets` exists and is a symbolic link.

From `man test`:

```
 -L FILE
              FILE exists and is a symbolic link (same as -h)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I was trying to google it and the - must have been throwing off my search! It also never occurred to me that a command could start with a dash like that. I was assuming the -L was an option to the env command or something.

Comment: I've updated the answer with more information on what the square brackets do, `-L` is indeed an option.